# Looking to create a batch file to execute multiple PowerShell commands to run a Modded Minecraft Server

Tags: powershell, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I run a Minecraft Java Modded server on my computer. The only way to run it is to use PowerShell and change the directory to where the jar file is located, then type "java -jar server.jar" for example. How can I make a batch file to do this so that all I have to do is click on the batch file every time I want to run the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a shortcut to `powershell.exe -file "c:\path\to\file\launcher.ps1"`.

The PowerShell file (launcher.ps1) should contain these lines:

```
Set-Location "C:\Minecraftfolder\jarfiles"
java -jar server.jar
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct, so the question doesn't remain open.